# How do I change the tableView library in Corona SDK for Retina Graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, lua, retina-display, coronasdk

I am checking out Corona SDK and looking to adapt the Coffee Demo ( http://blog.anscamobile.com/2010/09/create-scrolling-list-views-with-text-and-graphics-in-coronasdk-ios-android-tutorial/ ) so that it uses the Retina Display @2x image configuration described here: http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/01/dynamic-image-resolution-made-easy/

What would I need to do to integrate the Retina 4 stuff into the tableView library and thus make the Coffee Demo auto Retina 4 image compatible?

Comment: you've given the same link twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an "Interface Widget" available in Corona that produces tableViews that are compatible with retina displays:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/widgetnewtableview

And more Corona SDK user interface widgets here:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/widget

Answer (score 0):

the answer is on the second link you provided... I quote:

> As noted above, dynamic image resolution works in conjunction with dynamic content scaling (documented in the “Configuring Projects” section of the documentation). For further reference, the dynamic image resolution docs arehere.
>
> To use this feature, you basically need to do two things:
>
> 1. Use display.newImageRect() rather than display.newImage() when loading your images
> 2. Specify one or more scaling thresholds in your project’s config.lua file
>      The syntax is as follows:
>
> **display.newImageRect( [parentGroup,] filename [, baseDirectory] imageWidth, imageHeight )**
>
> - **imageWidth** is the base image’s width in the base dimensions of the content.
> - **imageHeight** is the base image’s height in the base dimensions of the content.
> - **parentGroup** and **baseDirectory** are optional, and can be omitted; they behave in the same way as their counterparts in display.newImage().